# Is X-Bulk header supported for Europe and Canada regions?

Tags: clio-api

Currently, we have integration with Clio USA API. We want to support also Europe and Canada regions. To get data we add `X-Bulk` header with value `true`. It works fine for USA API but returns 403 for EU and CA APIs. Is `X-Bulk` header supported for Europe and Canada regions?

Without `X-Bulk` header we receive response from EU and CA API. So, token is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clio is in the process of deprecating the X-Bulk/Bulk request header.

Clio turned off this feature for any new App Keys/Secrets created after January 2022.

Bulk requests will be ultimately removed entirely at some time in the future

Clio is encouraging all developers to adjust the functionality to not use Bulk Requests.